# using jwt with jwt-express with middleware in express js

Tags: express, jwt, express-jwt

In [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt) home page introduce a function for getting json web token from header or query that we can use as express middle wear and this is the function :

```
app.use(jwt({
secret: 'hello world !',
credentialsRequired: false,
getToken: function fromHeaderOrQuerystring (req) {
if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(' ')
[0] === 'Bearer') {
    return req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
} else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
  return req.query.token;
}
return null;
}
}));
```

And I use `express.Route()` like this :

```
app.use('/user',userRoute);
app.use('/apps',appsRouter);
```

My question is how can I use `getToken()` function or how can I access to the `token` in authorization of header.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i find the  solution. with middle ware (jwt) can verify the token in header and if can it set in `req.user` so , in `req.user` we have all information of deceded jwt, according to this:

> By default, the decoded token is attached to req.user but can be 
>        configured with the requestProperty option.
>     `jwt({ secret: publicKey, requestProperty: 'auth' });`

Answer (score 0):

I think , if i am not wrong, you need the token or the decoded one in your routes. Here's how i did it.

I Have a middle ware function that will decode the token for me which has the user information in it and then it will add the decoded object to the req object.

```
e.g route
.put('/update', Middleware.decodeToken, yourCallBackfunction)

decodeToken(req, res, next) {


            authorization = req.headers.authorization.replace('Bearer ', ''),
            decodeToken = Jwt.verify(authorization);
            //verifies the token

            req.tokenInfo = decodeToken
            next();
    }
```